# In differentiability

Tags: calculus, analysis, derivatives, partial-derivative

Let $f(x,y)$ and $g(x,y)$ are differentiable functions in $x$ and $y$. Suppose $f(x,y) = F(g(x,y))$.My question, Is $F$ differentiable function?!.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so.
Take $g:t\rightarrow t^2$ and $F:t\rightarrow |t|$.
Then  $f=t\rightarrow t^2$, $g$ and $f$ are differentiable at $0$, but $F$ is not.

You'll need another property, such as local invertibility of $g$ in a neighborhood of $(x,y)$, in which case it should result directly from the invert function theorem : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem

Comment: The original question said that $f$ and $g$ were functions of two variables

Comment: If it doesn't work for one variable, how can it work for two ? But if you insist, you can add a unused variable and the example still holds : $g:(x,y)\rightarrow x^2$ and $F:(x,y)\rightarrow |x|$.

Comment: Your counter example works in both one and two variables.

Comment: Yes, I don't actually think there's actual importance in the number of variables of whichever of the spaces. It's more like $f$ can be differentiable while $F$ is not because passing through $g$ can prevent you from exploring the local neighborhood of $F$, which you need to do to check its differentiability. Basically the entire information about $F$ might not be contained in $f$.